Is there a way to convert GOPRO MAX .360 files to .mp4 without using the gopro player app?
I have a gopro max camera that I use to record 360-degree VR footage. Up until now i have been using the official gopro player app to convert my .360 footage to .mp4, however, I am finding that the app really isn't that great, and from the looks of it, it could stop working due to lack of support any day.
I would like a more high-quality alternative, such as an FFMPEG command or an alternative software that supports more options, and generally works better on windows.
I've come across this site, which explains exactly what I ideally want to accomplish, however, all the commands to build the custom ffmpeg are for linux or something I'm not familiar with, and they dont work on windows: https://www.trekview.org/blog/using-ffmpeg-process-gopro-max-360/
Perhaps there is a pre-built binary of that somewhere? If not, maybe theres a way to build that on windows that I wasnt able to find? Or a different software altogether?
